# Google Earth Engine, 'computation time out' error when calculating area of binary masked

Tags: google-earth-engine

Using Landsat 8 TOA, I tried to find the area of mndwi pixel using binary masking, but its giving computation time out.
https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/c1a91260ff1628376dd19ff7f938261d
asset:https://code.earthengine.google.co.in/?asset=users/013limmazumms/Maharashtra_district